# How do i separate my code into different threads?

Tags: python, pygame

when i use sleep() the entire thing sleeps but I only want the things below it to sleep. I'm pretty sure that this is because they are all in the same thread right? so I'm wondering how I can separate them. I'm not familiar with pygame.time.get_ticks() so I need to still use sleep()

````
pygame.init()
from time import sleep

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400))

PINK = (255,192,203)
WHITE = (255,255,255)


screen.fill(PINK)
pygame.display.update()


font = pygame.font.SysFont("mvboli", 72)


text = font.render("loading", True, WHITE)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.center = (225,40)
screen.blit(text,textrect)




sleep(1)
text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.center = (350,40)
screen.blit(text,textrect)
sleep(0.5)
text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.center = (370,40)
screen.blit(text,textrect)
sleep(0.5)
text = font.render(".", True, WHITE)
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.center = (390,40)
screen.blit(text,textrect)
sleep(0.5)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, PINK, (340,0,100,500))

        




pygame.display.update()```
````

Comment: *"but I only want the things below it to sleep"* what's that?

Comment: You would be best served by learning about the python event model.  There is a great book by Al Sweigart "*Making Games with Python & Pygame*" which you can read for free.  Chapter2 discusses the PyGame event model - http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is because the point of a sleep function is to just stop the operation for a certain amount of time, you also need to import time and do time.sleep